# Remove foundation completely in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

How do i remove Foundation completely in a rails project? I used `rails g foundation:install` for installation after adding it to the `Gemfile`.
I have already removed it in the `Gemfile` but i am still getting Foundation-related errors in the browser.

Comment: Hi! Add error messages to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the [manual installation from foundation](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-rails#manual-installation). It should be enough reverting those steps

> Add Foundation to your CSS
>
> Append the following line to your app/assets/stylesheets/application.css file:

```
/*= require foundation
```

> If you're planning on using Sass, then you'll want to rename application.css to application.scss. That file should then look like:

```
@import "foundation_and_overrides";
/* Add imports of custom sass/scss files here */
```

so be sure to remove those files from your `application.css` or `application.scss`

> Add Foundation to your JS
>
> Append the following lines to your app/assets/javascripts/application.js file:

```
//= require foundation
$(document).foundation();
```

Remove those files and `.foundation()` call from `application.js`

> Set Viewport Width
>
> Add the following line to the head of your page layout:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

I have the viewport width set up like that for bootstrap, I don't think it should cause any problem.

> from [Cess](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6427830/cess)
> that worked, i also had to delete all the contents `_settings.css`

Comment: Thanks that worked i also had to delete all the contents _settings.css

Comment: thanks a lot @Cess ! would be very kind if you accept my answer